# Use code variable in org-mode continuous text

Tags: org-mode

I want to run a short python simulation in org-mode and use the results later
on in my continuous text. Something like:

```
#+begin_src python
a = 5 + 5
#+end_src

The result of the calculation is <<value in a>>
```

Which should export to the following latex code

```
The result of the calculation is 10.
```

Comment: You need to give a name to this block (`#+name: foo`) and then use it like this: `call_foo()` instead of `<<value in a>>`.

Comment: yeah that works. It will only print the last evaluated statement, so only `5+5` will work. Plus I have to write new cell for every variable that I want to export. I'll keep looking if I find something better.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind evaluating the whole code on export every time, you can do this:

Give the code block a session and later use inline code to call the variable, as in:

```
#+begin_src python :session calc :exports code :results none
a = 5 + 5
#+end_src

The result of the calculation is src_python[:session calc]{a}
```

There is another way which may not be worth the hassle for small code-blocks (depending on how complex it is in the language you are working in; R gave me problems...), but where you don't have to run the code always on export (results are persistent, but updated when you re-run the code block) using Macros that are prepared *within* the code-block as Macro Strings. At least, calling the results is then easier in-text:

```
#+begin_src python :session calc :exports code :results values drawer
a = 5 + 5
b = a-1
ares = '#+MACRO: a '+ str(a)
bres = '#+MACRO: b '+ str(b)
ares + '\n' + bres
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
#+MACRO: a 10
#+MACRO: b 9
:END:

The result is still {{{a}}} and b is {{{b}}}
```

Comment: This actually gave me: "The result of the calculation is a". I expected 10 instad of a. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: that's strange, I get 10. If you copy-paste the gray box above to a new file, does it also happen? what  if you change to `:results values`, and add a line below `a = 5 + 5`, only with `a`, so that a will be returned in a `#+RESULTS:` line (it should be `10`, ot `a`)

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work this night, It works now. Thank you. Btw I found that what I really want is to add an [`:results raw`](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html) so the 10 is formated as raw org text.

Comment: Glad it works, with raw you get the result inserted, yes, but it's not so easy to integrate it in-text as you pose in your example. If your question is answered please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, the real finding was that the org manual is indeed covering this quite good. I would accept your answer if it was mine, but in this case it is up to @kain88

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Babel away!